# How to *correctly* upload a WAR and its dependencies to Tomcat7 in Ubuntu

Tags: servlets, classpath, tomcat7

I would like to know how to upload a WAR file separated from its dependencies.
For example, you upload al the dependecies and leave them in the classpath
then you upload your WAR file without the dependencies packed in it.
When you are testing you servlet this is very useful as you don´t have to upload
a big WAR file with small changes everytime you need to correct something.

The problem is that sometimes it works and some other times it doesn´t.

So is there an official *correct* way of doing this?

Of course just packing everything into the WAR file does the job.

Comment: A war file is a complete web app--without its dependencies, how would it work?

Comment: Of course i can`t work without the dependencies, but you can "upload" the dependencies first, and then upload the web-app. So if you are debugging it is very useful to upload 15kb rather than 15Mb each time you do a small change. I think my question wasn´t clear, sorry.

Comment: ... A war file is a *complete* web-app, including its dependencies. How will you separate the two?

Comment: A simple example. If you write a Jax-Ws webservice using Netbeans then you have the option to not include the dependencies in the war file. This option appears in the Properties-->Libraries-->Compile tab, of the project. Then you can build your app without the dependencies, actually i removed the Metro 2.0 webservice stack, which reduced the War size in more than 20mb, and after uploading to the server, it works. This is not happening with some other dependencies, and that's why i ask this. Is there a *correct* way?

Comment: Then whatever you were deploying too had the libraries in the container path. That may or may not work depending on the libraries in question. It also forces all apps in the container to use the same version, which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WAR file has dependencies that are outside of it, then you will need to restart Tomcat whenever you update those dependencies: there is no such thing as a CLASSPATH for a WAR file other than what the container builds for you (which will include the stuff in the webapp's WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/*.jar, plus all the libraries guaranteed to be available by the container like servlet.jar, etc.).

Tomcat allows you to use a shared lib directory but that doesn't auto-reload when libraries are updated, which is likely to be causing the "inconsistent" behavior that you are observing.

The *official* correct way of doing this is to upload the whole WAR file: that's what they are for.

Comment: Restarting tomcat after uploading something, i'll give it a try, just for debugging purposes. Thanks for a good answer.